# Subquery to get Categories and data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Using MongoDB, NodeJs and Meteor, I have 2 collections setup like this:

Categories:
 * Food
 * Lifestyle
 * Other

Items:

```
1. CategoryId: 1 (food)
* Pizza

2. CategoryId: 1 (food)
* Spaghetti

3. CategoryId: 2 (lifestyle)
* Ziplining

4. CategoryId: 2 (lifestyle)
* Fishing
```

Ultimately, I’m trying to produce a result in the template that looks like this:

```
Food:
 * Pizza
 * Spaghetti

Lifestyle:
 * Ziplining
 * Fishing

Other:
```

I’m thinking the best way to do this would be to do a query that pulled in the categories, pulled out the category id’s, then did a second query with the category ids, looped through the results and stitched it all together into a single, multi-dimensional json object that I could parse through with the template.
Now comes the tricky part… I haven’t been able to find documentation on how to do this, since mainly mongo is designed for denormalized data.

Comment: Can you show some example documents?

Comment: If you’re looking for code, I don’t have any for this. I’m feeling a little lost at the moment.
My Category Collection looks like this: https://www.evernote.com/l/ASICpfUhw09PD5QRWsd_LHSzFl5C02judkg I’m still very new to MongoDB, so I didn’t realize that the _id isn’t a simple integer.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple to do :

```
let categoryId = Categories.findOne({<Your query here>});
let resultCursor = Items.find({CategoryId:categoryId});
```

The query in the first line depends on your document structure.

Comment: Not exactly what I’m after, but I’m not sure I can actually get what I’m after. I just pulled up the Collections and the id’s aren’t simple integers, but objectId’s. Looks like I would have to use DBRef somehow, but I‘m not sure it’s worth the effort. Screenshot of my Category Collection: https://www.evernote.com/l/ASICpfUhw09PD5QRWsd_LHSzFl5C02judkg

Comment: So what I’m after would be to do a single query on the categories, get all the categories, then do a query on the items Collection and pull all of the items that are associated with those categories.

Comment: It would still work. Just use find() instead of findOne() in the first statement and execute the second statement inside a loop on the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your `Items` look like `{ _id, categoryId, name }` and your `Categories` look like `{ _id, name }`

Then you're just trying to display a hierarchy across two collections.

Blaze (html):

```
<template name="hierarchy">
<ul>
{{#each categories}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
  <ul>
  {{# each items _id }} <!-- here _id is the _id of a category -->
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

Helpers (js):

```
Template.hierarchy.helpers({
  categories: function() {
    return Categories.find({},{sort: {name: 1}})
  },
  items: function(_id){
    return Items.find({categoryId: _id},{sort: {name: 1}})
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll have to try it later on. Thank you!